# how to manually setup pptp vpn in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vpn, pptp

I tried to setup the pptp vpn in ubuntu i.e

```
 /etc/ppp/peers/myvpn
```

Its contents are

```
pty "pptp <host> --nolaunchpppd"
name myusername
remotename myvpn
linkname myvpn 
ipparam myvpn
usepeerdns
require-mppe
file /etc/ppp/options.pptp
```

But using this settings i can establish the tunnel and I even get the private IP of the VPN network , but I cannot ssh into any machine or not even ping to any other machine except for itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your machine is probably using the wrong interface to send out packets to machines in the VPN. After establishing the VPN tunnel, you usually have to set a route for the VPN:

```
ip r add $VPN-net via $Peer dev $VPN-device
```

e.g.:

```
ip r add 10.3.0.0/17 via 10.30.100.40 dev ppp0
```